# Can I execute linux crontab commands from an external file?

Tags: cron

I would like to use an external file with crontab commands and that are included in the linux crontab.

The reason is that I want to add hundreds of lines and edit via ssh it makes me very complicated and slow.

With an external file I can use WinSCP + Notepad++ for edit.

I know the "crontab file" command but I would like it to be added automatically for example every 10 minutes. also in the past I used this command and for some reason some lines did not work.

the file would include different execution times in each command

Is there any way to do it?

Regards

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so not suitable for Stack Overflow. Maybe try our sibling sites [su] or [unix.se] but read their guidelines (too) before posting there.

Comment: Edited, I have added all the corresponding information and deleted the post from https://superuser.com/ since it is not possible to delete it here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just create a script file with your commands and add a crontab entry to run that file. Keep in mind that that file must have execute permissions set on it.

Comment: Could it be more specific? an example would be fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab):

```
crontab file
```

Comment: as I say in my message that causes problems and for that reason I can't use that command

Comment: Were do you say that? Can you please [edit] your question to describe those problems in more detail? If this is not a suitable answer then what sort of answer are you hoping for?